# jQuery hide and show element and remember using cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9jN8L/

The idea is that sidebar will be shown and if the user clicks the link then it will hide and a cookie will be created and remember that they have hidden it. Should they click it again it will show the sidebar again and delete the cookie (this is why the code is duplicated inside the toggle method functions)

However the sidebar is hidden by default and it doesn't show when the link is clicked after it has been hidden... Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest going back through your older posts and finding some that had answers that were helpful.  You have quite the reputation but most people wont be willing to spend the time helping you because there is only a 56% chance that you will mark there answer as an accepted one.  Try to mark answers as correct when they solve your solution.

Comment: Sorry to troll, but:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704452/using-jquery-cookie-js-to-remember-hide-show-element

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009817/simple-code-to-show-hide-with-cookie

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949926/show-hide-using-toggle-saving-to-cookie

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779915/hide-and-show-content-based-on-cookie-value

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it though. I'm asking why **MINE** isn't working!

Comment: If I don't get the answer I need then I'm not gonna accept it... So sometimes you get questions without accepted answers and you can't delete them so don't have much option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jN8L/2/**

Replace `if($.cookie('HideSidebar', 'Yes'))` by `if($.cookie('HideSidebar') == 'Yes')`.
The first condition sets the `HideSidebar` cookie to "Yes", while the second (right) method checks whether `HideSidebar` equal "Yes".

About your previous (deleted) question: http://jsfiddle.net/Jx3pj/1/. You've forgotten to add the $.Cookie function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think if you are going to check the value of the cookie you need to do

```
if( $.cookie('HideSidebar') )
```

Instead of

```
if($.cookie('HideSidebar', 'Yes'))
```

Because the latter sets the value of the cookie to 'Yes'